# searching for list index to delete struct class from

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, compare, element

so basically i have the following problem:

I created a userdata struct:

```
[Serializable]
public struct UserData
{
    public int UserID;
    public string UserName;
    public int UserScore;
    public int UserAvatar; 
}
```

then i created a list, where i can store those UserData values, when new user is created:

```
[Serializable]
class SaveData
{
    public List<UserData> SaveData_User;

}

public class Data_Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
public List<UserData> userData = new List<UserData>();  
}
```

In the following function iam filling the SaveData_User list:

```
public void SetNewUser(string name, int avatar)
    {
        //save it directly
        UserData newUser = new UserData();
        newUser.UserID = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("userID") + 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("userID", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("userID") + 1);
        newUser.UserName = name;
        newUser.UserScore = 0;
        newUser.UserAvatar = avatar;

        userData.Add(newUser);

        SaveUserDataValues();
    }
```

Note: The SaveData_User list is Serializable, because i need to save the users for several sessions. Now the users can be deleted and i want to remove them from SaveData_User list by comparsion with their ID's in the following function:

```
public void DeleteUser(int compareID)
    {
        /*PROBLEM HERE!!
        //Find index of id in the userData with the compareID (note compareID should be compared with the UserID element of UserData struct)
        */PROBLEM HERE!!    


        //Then remove at and save changes
        //userData.RemoveAt("valueMIssed");

        //SaveUserDataValues(); 
    }
```

has someone an idea how to compare the values and get me the index of the compareID value in my SaveData_User List to delete those UserData?

Note: Saving and loading userData into SaveData_User works well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I've read your question 3 times and still don't have a clue what is it that you're asking about. is it about finding and deleting an entry from a list?

Comment: Hey zambari, thanks for your answer! Yes basically iam adding those UserData (struct) to a list (userData) and i want to delete a special user i created before (therefore i have to get the index of the special value, because there could be added more users during runtime). Its all about finding the id in the userData list, get the struct UserData value and delete it from the userData list. (everything else works finde with saving loading the SaveData_User list) probably this is confusing in my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 int indexToLocate = -1;
 for(int i = 0; i < userData.Count; i++)
 {
   if (userData[i].UserID.Equals(compareID))
   {
     indexToLocate = i;
     break;
   }
 }

 if (indexToLocate != -1)
 {
    userData.RemoveAt(indexToLocate);
 }
```

First you will need to load the saved data in your userData if its already not loaded or refreshed. Then you will need to manually check if the UserID matches with compare ID in forloop. If it matches save the index from loop. Break away from the loop and remove the element at the index. After this save the updatedUserData so it will be written back in your savefile.

---

This will return you the element:

```
UserData userDataToRemove = userData.Find(x => x.UserID.Equals(compareID));
if (userData.Contains(userDataToRemove))
{
  userData.Remove(userDataToRemove);
}
```

This will return you the index:

```
int indexToLocate = userData.FindIndex(x => x.UserID.Equals(compareID));
if (indexToLocate != -1)
{
    userData.RemoveAt(indexToLocate);
}
```

Comment: Hello killer_mech - thank you very much for your answer! The for loop solution looks nice! Do you also know how to use the userData.Find() or userData.FindIndex() function (i tried this and i could not bring them to work - maybe because a list in a list is to 
interleaved)? I thougth a for loop wouldnt be the "state of the art" in this case, but it seems its the savest solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: @IDK you can also use above methods. I have updated the answer. There are many method to iterate and get id. Ofcourse we can always fallback on for loop if you are too confused to use advanced methods to find like the predicate matching. Never forget your basics and don't be ashamed to use it.

Comment: You brought it on point - i thought its time to learn the more advanced methods - but on the other hand i couldnt handle them yet. Thank you very much for your nice answers! You helped me a lot! Edit: Now i understand how to use those methods - very nice! Thank you!